# How to set array in redux toolkit?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, redux-toolkit

I dont know how to change Starter or any kind of key's value in the player? If the player is not a array i know how to do,but i have no idea about how to set array's value.(I guess this may use filter but i don't know actually how to do)

```
const playerSlice = createSlice({
    name: "player",
    initialState:{
        player:[
         {
           Name: 'cc',
           Starter:true,
           key:'1',
         },
        ]
   },
 
    reducers: {
        setPlayer:(state,action){
        //how to set Starter?
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Please format your question to be readable and then also actually ask a question with a full sentence. We are all human beings here - and we all would have to guess what you mean by "how to set starter".

Comment: Sorry my English is bad,and this is my first post, I didn't notice that format is important. Anyway,I have edit my post ,please check out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the `starter`-property of the first player in the array, you can access that at index `0`.

```js
state.player[0].Starter = false
```

Comment: One should never update the state directly ..

Comment: @Goran.it Unless they are using Redux Toolkit, which they are and which is the official recommendation for any new Redux code since 2019. See [writing reducers with immer](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers) and [why Redux Toolkit is how to use Redux today](https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today)

Comment: But what if i want to select other player? and why can't  I use this method to change value.                                                                                                          
           'setPlayer:(state,{payload})=>{
    
                 state.player[payload].Starter=!state.player[payload].Starter;                                          
    }'

Comment: Because you have no variable named `payload`. It is `action.payload` - and then it should work, assuming you also `dispatch(setPlayer(1))` (or similar).

Comment: I already change to action.payload,but also have error .                                     TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'state.player[payload].Starter')

Comment: It depends on what you pass in as `payload` when dispatching the action - it seems you pass in a payload for a player that just doesn't exist.

Comment: You are right, and now it's all correct,thank you!!!

Comment: @phry nice tip .. I actually didn't know that, i continued to use the old approach lol ..